# Need a function to convert decimal value to hexadecimal using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

With below convert statement i am able to get only the below result.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), '9133') 

result = 0x39313333
```

Is there any way to get the result as below.

```
result = 0x0039003100330033
```

Comment: Why do you want that result, it isn't even correct?

Comment: or is it supposed to be `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), N'9133')`

Comment: I'd suggest posting that as an answer @Squirrel. It certainly seems the OP seems to mean an `nvarchar`, rather than a `varchar` (although, why is the OP storing a numerical value as a string..?).

Comment: actually using asp when i convert a number 9133 to hexa decimal i get the  response as 0039003100330033.  i need to use same function to convert decimal to hexa decimal in SQl

Comment: can you show us that section of code in your asp ?

Answer (score 1):

try like below for hexa conversion from decimal

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), 9133) as hexa_output 

   hexa_output
    0x000023AD
```